# After I place redstone, the surrounding blocks disappear?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I don't have that much redstone on any of my maps. However, lately whenever I use any redstone on any of my maps, the pistons, redstone and the blocks next to them are disappearing.

Why is this happening? It seems to happen immediately after I finish setting it up, right in front of me. I have even tried to start a new map, but it still happens. It does not matter whether I'm on creative or survival.

It is definitely not due to endermen or pranks, because, like I said, it happens immediately after I finish it. There's no one else there to do anything. How can I fix this problem?

I have no mods

ps. I play on the xbox one

Comment: Also your text makes no sense. *blocks nest to them are disappearing*

Comment: Do you have any mods?

Comment: Where was this copy of Minecraft downloaded from?

Comment: @TimmyJim They said 'I have no mods'.

Comment: @haykam when I commented, that was not the case.  [See the edit history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/298304/revisions).

Comment: @TimmyJim It was an update so you could come back.

Answer (score 2):

That definitely doesn't sound like expected behavior. Here are the first things I would try:

- If you have any mods, disable them. The kind of behavior you're describing seems like it would only happen with a rogue mod. If removing all mods solves the problem, you can add mods back in one at a time to determine which one is the culprit.
- If you're not on the latest version of Minecraft, try updating. Again, this would be best done without any mods in place.

Comment: i dont have any mods